# Random forest optimisation

Tags: for-loop, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction

I have this code but it has to iterate over 2000 columns and 3000 rows, can someone help me to avoid the for loop?
Data are the classical taken from yahoo finance pack so they has adj close, close, high, low, volume; to make the model comparable I download the data and save them into the file 'data full 10'.

This is my code, can someone help me to create a function to avoid it?
Thank you in advice

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv("data 10 full.csv", index_col=[0], header=[0,1])

# Get number of stocks
num_stock = len(data['Adj Close'].columns)

# Define window size
window_size = 60

# Define grid for hyperparameter tuning
grid_rf = {
    'n_estimators': [500],  
    'max_depth': [5,10,15,20,25,30],  
    'min_samples_split': [2,5,10,15,20,25,30], 
    'min_samples_leaf': [1,5,10,15,20,25,30]
}

# Initialize predictions array
predictions = []

# Define a function to perform the random search and return the trained model
def train_model(x_train, y_train):
    # Drop rows that are not present in both datasets
    idx = x_train.index.intersection(y_train.index)
    x_train = x_train.loc[idx]
    y_train = y_train.loc[idx]

    # Fit randomized search cross validation
    model = RandomForestRegressor() 
    rscv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=model, param_distributions=grid_rf, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2, n_iter=40)
    x_train = x_train.fillna(0)
    y_train = y_train.fillna(0)
    rscv_fit = rscv.fit(x_train, y_train)
    best_parameters = rscv_fit.best_params_

    # Train model
    model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=best_parameters['n_estimators'], 
                                   min_samples_split=best_parameters['min_samples_split'], 
                                   min_samples_leaf=best_parameters['min_samples_leaf'], 
                                   max_depth=best_parameters['max_depth'])
    model = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    return model


# Define a function to make predictions on a single window
def predict_window(window, model):
    x_test = window.iloc[-1,:-num_stock].fillna(0)
    prediction = model.predict(x_test.values.reshape(1, -1))
    return prediction[0]

# Use rolling to iterate over windows
models = []
for i in range(window_size+1, len(data)):
    # Get current window
    window = data.iloc[i-window_size-1:i]

    # Define training and testing data
    x_train = window.iloc[:-1,:-num_stock].fillna(0)
    y_train = window.iloc[:-1,num_stock:].fillna(0).shift(-1).dropna()

    # Train model and store it
    model = train_model(x_train, y_train)
    models.append(model)

    # Make predictions and append to list
    prediction = predict_window(window, model)
    predictions.append(prediction)

# Convert predictions to dataframe and set index
predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=data.columns.get_level_values(0))
predictions_df.set_index(data.index[window_size+1:], inplace=True)

# Calculate root mean squared error
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(data.iloc[window_size+1:, :num_stock], predictions_df))
print('RMSE: ', rmse)

# Plot actual and predicted data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(data.index, data.iloc[:, :num_stock])
plt.plot(predictions_df.index, predictions_df)
plt.legend(['Actual', 'Predicted'])
plt.show()
```